# Peugeot 207 gti depollution fault

Tags: engine, peugeot, timing

Car starts rough but runs fine ,no loss of power. check engine light on and depollution system faulty on dash. Local garage scanned car and came up with camshaft sensor fault but they think timing chain . This was changed in 2011 so has it gone again ?

Comment: How many miles (KMs) on the vehicle (total) and how many since the chain was changed? While I don't like *Remove & Replace* (R&R) mechanics, this may be one of those times where trying to replace the camshaft sensor might save you some money. I'll assume getting the chain replaced is going to be a lot more expensive. Also, you may consider taking it to a second garage for a separate opinion.

Comment: 100,000 on clock now chain replace at 68,045 miles. will go to peugeot garage on monday for second opinion.